# Database error recovering from misfires Qualtz

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I configured Quartz to use scheduled jobs from the database.
Now when I start the scheduler with:

```
try {
  // Grab the Scheduler instance from the Factory
  Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();


  // and start it off
  scheduler.start();

  scheduler.shutdown();

} catch (Exception se) {
  Log.log(LogLevel.ERROR, se.getMessage());
}
```

The config file of the project looks like:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = DatabaseScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = true
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 3

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.MSSQLDelegate
org.quartz.dataSource.myDB.driver = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
org.quartz.dataSource.myDB.URL = jdbc:sqlserver://server:1433;databaseName=schedules
org.quartz.dataSource.myDB.user = sa     
org.quartz.dataSource.myDB.password = password
org.quartz.dataSource.myDB.maxConnections = 2

org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDB
org.quartz.scheduler.misfirePolicy =  doNothing
```

The error that I got is:

```
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Database error recovering from misfires. [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: An SQLException was provoked by the following failure: java.lang.InterruptedException]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doRecoverMisfires(JobStoreSupport.java:3213)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:3951)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.run(JobStoreSupport.java:3972)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: An SQLException was provoked by the following failure: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:65)
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:62)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache.acquireStatement(GooGooStatementCache.java:562)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache.checkoutStatement(GooGooStatementCache.java:168)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.checkoutStatement(NewPooledConnection.java:234)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.prepareStatement(NewProxyConnection.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.java:73)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.countMisfiredTriggersInState(StdJDBCDelegate.java:390)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doRecoverMisfires(JobStoreSupport.java:3192)
    ... 2 more
```

Can someone help me with this error? I have also looked at the stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31423003/quartz-error-misfire-handling-and-failure-on-job-recovery). Without any luck. I'm using Quartz 2.2.3. Even when my database tables are empty I got the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. In my source code the scheduler start and immediately close the scheduler. In this time nothing can be scheduled and also the start of the scheduler was not finished before the close has been called. Removing the close call it worked correctly.